# Java consecutive sign cause SignatureException?

Tags: java, security, cryptography, digital-signature, smartcard

I am unable to sign stuff twice in a row... Is this a known Java crypto issue?

My reduced test case

```
public class Test {

    private X509Certificate cert = null;
    private PrivateKey pk = null;

    public Test(X509Certificate cert, Key pk) {
        this.cert = cert;
        this.pk = (PrivateKey) pk;
    }

    public byte[] sign(byte[] data) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, SignatureException {
        Signature rsa = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
        rsa.initSign(pk);
        rsa.update(data);
        return rsa.sign();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Load your cert here
        //X509Certificate cert ...
        String data = "Hello World";

        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");
        ks.load(null, null);
        Key pk = ks.getKey(cert.getAlias(), null);

        Test test = new Test(cert, pk);

        // Signing once
        Logger.debug(test.sign(data.getBytes()));
        // Signing twice
        Logger.debug(test.sign(data.getBytes()));

    }
}
```

The first sign operation went fine as expected, however the second sign operation throws the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.SignatureException: 
The card cannot be accessed because the wrong PIN was presented.

at sun.security.mscapi.RSASignature.signHash(Native Method)
at sun.security.mscapi.RSASignature.engineSign(RSASignature.java:386)
at java.security.Signature$Delegate.engineSign(Signature.java:1207)
at java.security.Signature.sign(Signature.java:579)
at ca.carillon.piv.signer.SignWorker.sign(SignWorker.java:48)
at ca.carillon.piv.signer.SignWorker.sign(SignWorker.java:39)
at ca.carillon.piv.signer.SignWorker.main(SignWorker.java:75)
```

Now the thing is, the second signing operation, it never even prompted me to enter the PIN.

Can someone tell me what's wrong? I'm pretty sure my code is correct...

**Update:**

If you run the above code with software certificate, then it will sign fine. It seems it will only craps out when dealing with hardware certificate with PIN.

If I change the code to the following, then it would sign the second time, however, it add a **significant amount of delay** since it has to reload the keystore...

```
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");
    ks.load(null, null);

    Test test = new Test(cert.getCertificate(), 
    ks.getKey(cert.getAlias(), null));
    Logger.debug(test.sign(test));

    // if I reload it like this
    ks.load(null, null);
    Logger.debug(test.sign(test));
```

If anyone else have more insight or a better workaround on this, that would be nice. Please let me know!

Comment: You probably need to configure some kind of callback handler for this.

Comment: Neither `ks.load(null, null);` or `Key pk = ks.getKey(cert.getAlias(), null);` provide any PIN, nor do you call `Key pk = ks.getKey(cert.getAlias(), null);` twice (just to be sure). Could you try adding a PIN that way?

Comment: You don't provide the PIN, it prompts you. There seems to be a bug with sunmscapi.jar, if I reload the keystore before signing, then it would work.

Comment: I would certainly at least *try* my solutions. Note that there is a difference between cards if they require PIN before each RSA private key operation or only once. It could well be that the software CAPI implementation does not provide the required information to sunmscapi, so I would not blame that library prematurely - it might be correct.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I did tried your way before I even post it here in SO. I created 2 new instances of `Test` object and they perform `getKey` in both occasion. The only time I got it to "work" is with my workaround mention in my update by reloading the KeyStore, heck I don't even need to get key for the subsequent signing. But that's a bad workaround...